# Какой алгоритм более оптимальный?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Какой из алгоритмов наиболее оптимальный - `O(n)`, `O(log(n))` или `O(n * log(n))`?

Comment: Сложность алгоритма связана с его эффективностью как бы не напрямую - там всегда присутствует скрытая константа. Сложность позволяет оценить количество итераций, но ничего не говорит о времени и ресурсах на одну итерацию. Так что в реальности алгоритм с бОльшей формально сложностью может быть более эффективным. Только на гипер-больших объёмах можно более-менее гарантировать, что менее сложный алгоритм эффективнее - т.е. всегда есть точка, за которой менее сложный алгоритм начинает выигрывать, но она далеко не всегда в начале.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очевидно, что *глобально* `O(log n)` быстрее `O(n)`, а тот быстрее `O(n*log n)`. Но это теория :)

Но локально могут быть разные входные данные, разные реализации - так что при *реальной* работе алгоритм с лучшей асимптотикой может показывать худшую производительность.

Не следует также забывать и о расходах, например, памяти - вполне может оказаться, что для более быстрого алгоритма просто не хватит памяти.

Словом, если вы рассматриваете проблему с теоретической точки зрения - то так, как я написал в первой строке.

С практической при выборе конкретного алгоритма - надо пробовать и замерять...

Comment: можно еще [графики показать](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=yVJ-W7rKOuWqrgT99YrQCw&q=x*+ln%28x%29%2C+x%2C+ln%28x%29&oq=x*+ln%28x%29%2C+x%2C+ln%28x%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l2.11395.15520.0.15972.7.7.0.0.0.0.73.458.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.457....0.hQmmJqJy6iA)

Comment: я не понял насчет локального и глобального

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Глобально - значит, в самом общем случае, при суперогромных значениях N. Локально - для конкретных данных. Например, отсортировать практически отсортированный небольшой массив обычно быстрее вставками с O(n^2), чем чем-то с O(n lg n). Или - писать бинарный поиск для массива из нескольких элементов - никакого смысла...

Comment: @Harry теперь понял спасибо добавил плюс :)

Answer (score 2):

Асимптотическая сложность алгоритма, как правило берется в самом худшем случае - объем работы на каждую единицу входных данных. Эта сложность как правило относительная, на практике все зависит от входных данных.

Для примера вы можете взять несколько вариантов сортировок.

Допустим :

- BubleSort
- QuickSort
- BinarySort
- ShakeSort

И в каждый из них по очереди скармливать 10 вариантов входных данных и какими либо StopWatch смотреть на время сортировки, и проследить зависимость данных сортировок по времени и по входным данным сравнивая каждый с другим типом сортировки.

Оговорюсь еще раз - все зависит от входных данных, могут быть случаи когда при идентичных входных данных, разные алгоритмы с разными асимтотическими сложностями показывают интересные результаты - алгоритм с дорогой сложность может проделать работу быстрее чем алгоритм с более дешевой сложность.

Вот немного статей на предмет асимтотической сложности :

- [Знай сложности алгоритмов (habr)](https://habr.com/post/188010/)
- [Оценка сложности алгоритмов, или Что такое О(log n) (tproger)](https://tproger.ru/articles/computational-complexity-explained/)